# Decimal minutes into time format (Tabular Cube)

Tags: dax

I would like to change decimal minutes into HH:mm:ss (DAX, Tabular Cube).

When I use this : 
measure = FORMAT(TIME(0;minutes;0);"HH:mm:ss")
I get hours and minutes but without seconds. Minutes are rounded.

When I use this : 
measure = FORMAT(TIME(0;0;minutes*60);"HH:mm:ss")
I have an error that value is too big or too small.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX understands decimal time in units of days, so all that you need to do is convert decimal minutes to decimal days and format:

```
FORMAT ( [Minutes] / 60 / 24, "HH:mm:ss" )
```

Comment: I works but only for amount <1 .
For 1,1 days it shows 02:24:00 but I need duration (26:24:00)

Comment: I solved it : 
HHMMSS:=IF([Minutes]/60 > 0;format(int([Minutes]/60); "00") & ":" & format(([Minutes]/60)/24;"nn:ss"))